# Spring autowired environment is null when configuration for junit test

Tags: spring, junit, properties, configuration, environment

I'm trying to configure an h2 datasource for junit testing using Spring java configuration and loading properties from external file. When following the tutorials and using @PropertySource and autowiring the Environment I find that when creating the datasource the Environment is null. Does anybody know why the Environment is null when building the Datasource bean?

I have created a dummy Test class with ContextConfiguration pointing to a @Configuration class where I define the database connection required beans. To create those, I just want to use an external properties file, so i used @PropertySource pointing the file and use the Environment that should be populated with those properties. When I try to access any Environment property it fails because the Enviroment is null.

I also tried to create a PropertySourcePlaceHolder and populate with @Value but with the same result (the property is not populated).

If my configuration class implements EnvironmentAware interface, effectively it populates the environment for my datasource bean, so this way it works.

I also tested the same without creating any database bean and just creating a dummy bean that just prints a environment property in creation and  i found the same problem (Environment is null).

I suppose there should be something with spring initialization order by I cannot understand why it is not working because all examples are defining beans in the way I am trying.

```
//TEST CLASS
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {DataBaseTestConfiguration.class} , loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TestConfiguracion {
//Dummy
    @Test
    public void testPrueba(){
        assertEquals(1,1);
    }
}
```

My configuration class

```
//CONFIGURATION CLASS
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "es.bla.springmvcexample")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataBaseTestConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        System.out.println(environment); //<-- here is showing environment is null

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")); //<-- Here fails
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

 ....

}
```

Anybody could explain me why the Environment is not injected when creating the beans?

EDIT: I have created another @Configuration (PropertiesConfiguration) where I define @PropertiesSource and change the @ContextConfiguration to add that configurationClass. Then I have changed DataBaseTestConfiguration and filed inject the @Enviroment and it works. 
Adding a dummy Bean in PropertiesConfiguration and trying to autowire the Environment in that class for populating that bean, fails the same way. It's like if I could not autowire the environment in the Configuration class where it is defined (but I don't understand why the class where is defined matters)

Comment: Where is your @ComponentScan annotation?

Comment: There is not componentscan because the component is defined in the class with @configuration so it shouldnt be necessary I think